# How can I solve the 'TypeError: Descriptors cannot be created directly' error when importing certain TensorFlow libraries?

Tags: tensorflow

when working with tensorflow, while importing certain tensorflow libraries i am getting error

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tempfile, urllib, zipfile
!pip install tensorflow_data_validation
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from tensorflow_data_validation.utils import slicing_util
from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0.statistics_pb2 import DatasetFeatureStatisticsList, DatasetFeatureStatistics
```

i got error
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:

1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

More information: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates

Comment: Did you try anything that the error message suggests?

Answer (score 2):

This is common error of protobuf version mismatch with few modules and can be resolved after installing the protobuf version 3.20.

```
pip install protobuf==3.20
```

Please make sure that you install the **protobuf 3.20** after installing all other required modules so that protobuf version does not get changed while installing all the prior modules.